# IOS can't sync after renaming App.xcodeproj

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor

Hello i have manually renamed App.xcodeproj file to MyProject.xcodeproj. And now i can't sync my capacitor project `ios cap sync`

this is the error i am getting

```
[error] 2022-09-26 17:49:31.909 xcodebuild[11747:97674] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS
    of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-09-26 17:49:31.911 xcodebuild[11747:97674] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
    Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
    Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project App.xcodeproj clean
    
    User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
    
    xcodebuild: error: 'App.xcodeproj' does not exist.
    
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your error message, XCode is still looking for the old file `App.xcodeproj`:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project App.xcodeproj clean
```

Just rename your project to `App.xcodeproj` and it should work again.

Comment: Yes i did. i just wanted to be as my app name

Comment: @PellaPost Unfortunately for people who want to change the name, I think Ionic expects the name of the app file to be App, so there's no good way to change it and continue to use `cap sync` and other commands.  This is the price we have to pay for all the cool automation functionality provided by ionic.

Comment: Thanks Patrick i published the app as App anyway!!!